# Find listview position based on id

Tags: android, android-listview, android-cursoradapter

I have a ListView displaying data from a SimpleCursorAdapter. I have the id value and I want the position in the list, the opposite of getItemId(position). Is there such a functionality?

I know how to implement it (don't bother show code) but I just can't find it and it seems like an obvious method.

Comment: There is no method like this for the built-in adapters. If your ListView is sorted by the row ids then you can use a binary search (fast!), otherwise you're probably stuck with an exhaustive search (slow...).

Comment: I hoped I was blind and did not see it ;) Thx @Sam

Comment: By the way, I modified a [binary search for a Cursor](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12238244/1267661) a few hours ago. Use it if you like.

Comment: The order is unknown so I will go with the exhaustive search :/ If this cause speed issues I shall refactor so the order will be known and a binary search could be performed. Btw, I perform the exhaustive search on the listadapter (from 0 to count-1: if itemid==id break and return the index). Do you think this is slower than searching the underlying cursor?

Comment: Without seeing the code, I'm not sure. But remember the sage advice: "premature optimization is the root of all evil", basically don't worry about it if it is not a problem.

Comment: Can I ask why you're needing it? Typically knowing where the item is in the list is a detail you shouldn't need to worry about. (separating the view from the data and all that good stuff)

Comment: I want to navigate the list (like seeing a list of articles and then one article at a time with previous/next). But when I see the details of a specific item I only know it's id so I can load it. *one* implementation could be to pass the id to the list and the let the list pass me back the next (or previous) id so I load it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Brought up from comments**

There is no method like this for the built-in adapters. If your ListView is sorted by the row ids then you can use a binary search (fast!), otherwise you're probably stuck with an exhaustive search (slow...).

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution would be to set the id to child item in bind view

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, Cursor cursor {
      ..... 
      convertView.setId(id);
}
```

Later from the activity you can find this view by id and get the position

```
View yourChildViewWithSpecifiedId = yourListView.findViewById(id);
int position = yourListView.getPositionForView(yourChildViewWithSpecifiedId);
```